# Symfony 2.7: Forward to magic method login not working

Tags: php, symfony

**1. Systemcredentials:**

Using: 
symfony 2.7 ,
php 5.6,
Apache 2 as Webserver

**2. Problem:**

Trying to implement a facebook connect. The User can login on the login page and should be login from backend. The PHPSESSION Cookie need to be set. The frontend part call a backend function fbconnect. The fbconnect action checks that the form and the facebook credentials are valid. If the handover parameters are valid and connected to facebook and my application, the action 
forward to the magic login method from symfony. Now the magic login function should login the user, but the action seems to just set the cookie. I'm still an anon at this point. Maybe the event chain is broken at this point, because of the forward to the magic login action? Strange behaviour is that the fbconnect action is called twice, but in frontend part the method called once. Did I missed something special?

my parameter: facebook ID, facebook (valid) Accesstoken, facebook Email

**3. Code Snippets**

my **security.yml** file:

```
security:
    firewalls:
    ....
    ....
    webapi:
        provider: secureBundle
        pattern: ^/webapi
        anonymous:  ~
        form_login:
            login_path: webapi-login
            check_path: webapi-login-check
            default_target_path: webapi-login-success
            require_previous_session: false
```

Note: the "webapi-" part is dynamically add to the routes from the actions (Routing works properly)

**fbconnect Action:**

Note: the Action validate if the form is correct and that all parameters are valid, this is just the forward snippet.

```
$response = $this->forward(
'ApiBundle:Login:login',['/login/'], [
    '_password' => $passwordEncoder->decodePassword($user->getPassword(), null),
    '_username' => $user->getEmail(),
]
```

**Login Action**:

Note: the references come from symfony doc [Login Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) . The Action simply let symfony handle this and jetzt return a response.

```
 /**
 * @Route(path="/login/",name="login")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{

    $frame = $this->createFrame();

    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    if ($error) {
        $frame->setError(true, Errno::GENERAL_BAD_CREDENTIALS, [$error->getMessage()]);
    }

    return $frame;
}
```

**4. Conclusion**

Like I explained above i think that symfony can't handle a forward to the login. I don't unterstand why the the PHPSESSID Cookie is set, but im still anon. Do you have any experiences with this? I appreciate every hint.

Greeting Violence!

Comment: Did you check your profiler for form errors? Maybe there's a CSRF token missing.

Comment: @ccKep Form is correct. CSRF token exists. My frontend part get the parameters from fb this works. I give the backend the parameters as a post request. the action checks if the user is in my database and then forward with the user password and username like shown above. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I come up with this solution:**

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $frame = $this->createFrame();
    try {
        try {
            $user = $this->get('secure.user_provider')->loadUserByUsername($request->get('_username'));
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $exception) {
            $frame->setError($exception);

            return $frame;
        }
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'webapi', $user->getRoles());
        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
        $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch('security.interactive_login', $event);


        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        if ($error) {
            $frame->setError(true, Errno::GENERAL_BAD_CREDENTIALS, [$error->getMessage()]);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $frame->setException($e);
    }

    return $frame;
}
```

I created the login manually. Generate a UsernamePasswordToken and dispatch the event.

Hope it will help somebody with the same problem!